# periodictable example how to find element clicked?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am three.js noob.
I am playing with this sample
http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

I would like to know when a particular element is clicked, saw couple samples and added the code below
Set a break point inside the function, intersects.length is always 0 even when I click inside a element.
Please help! What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

```
    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();
        controls.enabled = true;

        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5 );
        //var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects,true );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

            intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

            var particle = new THREE.Particle( particleMaterial );
            particle.position = intersects[ 0 ].point;
            particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 8;
            scene.add( particle );

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Raycaster doesn't work with css3Drenderer.
just use the elments onclick event

Comment: Thank you Gero3 that was very helpfull. I was missing that conceptually and your answer has helped me move forward.